# frama-c gui warning Mime type 'text/x-csrc' not found

Tags: frama-c, gtksourceview

While running

```
frama-c-gui aluminium
```

on `open suse 13.1` gives a warning message:

> [gui] warning: Mime type 'text/x-csrc' not found

What could be the cause and solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frama-c is relying on the gtksourceview library to provide syntax highlighting in the GUI (both for the normalized code and the original source view). It thus asks gtksourceview for the language definition corresponding to the `text/x-csrc` mime type, corresponding to C source files. The warning is emitted if gtksourceview does not find such language definition.

You might want to check whether your installation of gtksourceview indeed includes proper language definitions (on my Debian, this is located under `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/`, and if not whether there is some package that could provide them.

Comment: gtksourceview-2.0 was not installed properly as /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/ directory was not present. After re installation from SUSE repository issue got resolved. Thanks